# Is there a formula for $\int^{b}_{a} x \text{ dx}$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

$\int^{b}_{a} x \text{ dx}$?

I agree it forms a triangle, but in the case where $b <0$, there's another triangle we have to factor in.

Is there a formula takes takes both of these into account, and just spits out the answer?

For ex) $\int^{2}_{-1} x \text { dx}$

Comment: Note (or, better, prove) that$\int^{2}_{-1} x \,dx = \int^{2}_{1} x \,dx\,$. Hint: $\int^{a}_{-a} x \,dx = 0\,$ for $\forall a\,$.

Comment: yes.  $\frac{b^2 - a^2}{2}$.  I assume you're in Calculus. Stay tuned!  $x^2/2$ is an antiderivative for $x$, and then the fundamental theorem of calculus gives you the result.

Comment: Yeah @Callus, I still gotta evaluate using area instead of antiderivative, if you put your answer in the description I can mark as correct

Comment: @dxiv, wow. I didn't know that ... thanks, I wonder why it works ..

Comment: @KSplitX $\int^{a}_{-a} f(x) \,dx = 0\,$ for any function that is odd i.e. $f(-x)=-f(x)\,$. Think at the point symmetry with respect to the origin, the areas left and right of the origin are congruent, but have opposite signs and cancel out.

Comment: Remember that if the area is under the $x$-axis, it counts as negative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The integral from $0$ to $b$ is $\frac12b^2$:

[image]

The integral from $0$ to $a$ is $\frac12a^2$:

[image]

Your integral is then as follows:

$$\int_a^bx\ dx=\int_0^bx\ dx-\int_0^ax\ dx=\frac12b^2-\frac12a^2$$

Comment: Nice application of desmos xD

Comment: @KSplitX Didn't quite know how to make the $a,b$ fit in better though :-P

Comment: Although in the integral you wrote $x^2$? I think you should fix

Comment: @KSplitX >.> What $x^2$?

Comment: LOOL nice edit :P

Answer (score 1):

The formula is

$$ \frac{1}{2} \left( b^2-a^2 \right) $$

Do you know why? What is the indefinite integral of $x$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a standard integration.

$$ \int _a^b x \; dx,$$
where upon integration becomes 
$$ \frac{x^2}{2} |^b_a = \frac{1}{2}(b^2 - a^2).$$
Voila! Enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $a<0$ and $b>0$. Spit the integral into, (this is the same as breaking up signed areas into two)

$$\int_{a}^{0} x dx+\int_{0}^{b} x dx$$

The first is going to be negative as it is below the $y$ axis, but it will in magnitude represent a triangle with base $a$ and height $a$. The second is going to be positive and represent a triangle with base $b$ and height $b$. So the integral is,

$$-\frac{1}{2}(a)(a)+\frac{1}{2}(b)(b)=\frac{1}{2}b^2-\frac{1}{2}a^2$$

There are a couple more cases to check $a,b>0$ which results in a trapezoid  with base $b-a$ and average height $\frac{b+a}{2}$. So again we get $(b-a)\frac{b+a}{2}=\frac{1}{2}(b^2-a^2)$. Then the case $a,b<0$ is going to be similar to this. And the case $a>0, b<0$ is going to be similar to the very first case we considered.